# Need to find return type method's lambda function parameter

Tags: java, lambda, reflection, pax-exam, junit5-extension-model

(Note.. I have restructured the example to more closely match the use case I am working on)

I have the following interface defined:

```
public interface Interceptor {
    <T> T intercept (Invocation<T> invocation);

    interface Invocation<T> {
        T proceed();
    }
}
```

This simplest implementation of this would be something like:

```
class TestInterceptor {
    static class Line {int x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2;}
    static class Color {int r, g, b;}
    static class Renderer {
        Interceptor interceptor;
        Renderer (Interceptor interceptor) {this.interceptor = interceptor;}
        void draw (Supplier<Line> lineSource, Supplier<Color> colorSource) {
            Line thisLine = interceptor.intercept(lineSource::get);
            Color thisColor = interceptor.intercept(colorSource::get);
            // do the drawing
        }
    }
    void drawSomething () {
        Renderer render = new Renderer(getInterceptor());
        render.draw( () -> createLine(), () -> createColor() );
    }
    Line createLine () {return new Line(/*something*/);}
    Color createColor () {return new Color(/*something*/);}
    Interceptor getInterceptor () {
        return new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            <T> T intercept (Invocation<T> invocation) {
                /* would like to do this:
                if (invocation.returnType = Line) {
                   return new MyLIne();
                } else {
                   return invocation.proceed();
                } */
               return invocation.proceed();
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Notice the comment in `getInterceptor()` that I would like to take different actions (including not calling the lambda) based on what the lambda is going to return. I have tried everything I can think of to get the actual type behind the parameterized type `T` but keep drawing a blank. Can anyone help me out here?

Here are some of the things I've tried

```
Class<?> wclass = interceptor.getClass();
Method method = wclass.getMethod("proceed", new Class<?>[]{});
Class<?> rtype = method.getReturnType(); //getName() always returns "java.lang.Object"
Type gtype = method.getGenericReturnType();
Class<?> gtclass = gtype.getClass(); //getName() always returns "java.lang.Class"
String gtname = gtype.getTypeName()); //always returns "java.lang.Object"
```

I am actually trying to create a "Remote Launcher" for JUnit5 so I can use Maven SureFire to run tests in a separatly launched and configured OSGi "container" (way overloaded term but don't get me started). Except for the `getInterceptor()` method, all of the sample code above is a simplification of existing Junit5 code and not anything I can change.

(Ideally, I would integrate the new Remote Launcher into PaxExam which seems to have stagnated.)

Comment: Correct the code in the block "simplest implemenation" so that it will compile, and we can discuss further …

Comment: So you want to write an implementation of WorkValidator.checkWork that will decide what action to take based on the generic parameter of the Worker argument?  Like, do one thing if the argument is `Worker<String>` and do another thing if the argument is `Worker<Integer>`?

Comment: The situation you're describing typically requires a different abstraction, and a different ordering of the data.  Can you provide more information regarding the application here, what is its purpose?

Comment: Restructured the question and its sample code. Also discussed what I am actually trying to do -- create a Remote Launcher for JUnit5

Comment: `if (invocation.returnType = Line)`  —Not possible.  Sorry, there is just no way to do this.  That information exists only at compile-time.  I realize you don’t control the signature of the `intercept` method, but somehow, your own code will have to require more information (specifically, a Class object) before creating an Interceptor, in order to know what that return type will be.

Comment: Note that `gtype.getClass()` does not do what you want at all.  It returns the class of the gtype reflection object itself, not the Class which is the method’s generic return type.  You may be able to get results from something like `if (gtype instanceof Class<?> cls) { String gtname = cls.getName(); /* etc. */ }`

Answer (score 0):

You can make the interface use a type parameter just like how Lists work in Java.

```
interface WorkValidator<T> {
    T checkWork (Worker<T> worker);

    interface Worker<T> {
        T doWork();
    }
}
```

Then your implementations can be specific implementations such as a string worker like so:

```
class StringWorkValidator implements WorkValidator<String> {
    @Override 
    public String checkWork (Worker<String> worker) {
        return worker.doWork();
    }
}
. . .
StringWorkValidator myValidator = new StringWorkValidator();
. . .
String finishedWork = myValidator.checkWork( () -> someWorker.work(p1, p2, etc) );
```

Comment: I can't change the `WorkValidator` interface or any of the code that invokes its implementations... it is all part of JUnit5 which I am trying to extend with a "Remote Launcher"

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou everyone for providing great feedback on my question. I am sorry if I was not completely clear in details of my problem.

VGR's comments corroborated what I was afraid of... that there isn't yet any way to do exactly what I have hoped for. Maybe a future Java release will allow this sort of deep reflection at runtime.

Anyway, the best solution I could come up with was to go ahead and call `invocation.proceed()` then use old-school Class.isAssignableFrom() to examine its result. Then return a replacement object instead. This would look like this...

```
return new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    <T> T intercept (Invocation<T> invocation) {
        T result = invocation.proceed();
        if (result != null && Line.class.isAssignableFrom(result.getClass()) {
            result = new MyLine((Line) result); // maybe MyLine needs to delegate actions
        }
        return result;
    };
```

Of course, this assumes there aren't any undesirable side effects of calling the lambda but replacing its results with your own.

Comment: Instead of `Line.class.isAssignableFrom(result.getClass())` you can simply use `result instanceof Line`. In either case, it tests the runtime type of the object, not the invoked method’s return type. E.g. you can write `Invocation<Object> i = Line::new;` then, the formal return type is `Object` but the actual return value has type `Line`. By the way, the `Invocation` interface is obsolete, you can use `Supplier<T>` in the first place, then you can simply pass through the suppliers without the need to adapt them.